# Selenium 4: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium4

I am trying to run my UI automation tests in a docker. Below are some relevant details:-

Docker Image:-"python:3.10"

Below is my gitlab-ci file which actually installs required stuff:-
before_script:

```
  - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
  - echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
  - apt-get update -q -y
  - apt-get install -y python3-pip
  - apt-get install libnss3
  - python -V
  - pip3 install -r requirements.text
```

I am using webdriver_manager to install drivers

```
def set_options_for_chrome(context):
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("window-size=1600,1440")
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
  options.add_argument('--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp')
  options.headless = context.headless
  options.binary_location = ChromeDriverManager().install()
  return options

context.driver= webdriver.Chrome(options=set_options_for_chrome(context))
```

The above code installs the chrome driver at below location:
/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/112.0.5615.49/chromedriver (so the downloading part looks fine to me)

Error:-
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/112.0.5615.49/chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)